# Purpose of Gitlab "Maintenance Note" for a Runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

It's the first time I make a pipeline for CI/CD in Gitlab. At a point, when registering the runner, we can *"Enter optional maintenance note for the runner"*.

I looked for more information about it, but I found nothing in GitLab documentation except for [Admin Notes](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/support/workflows/admin_note.html) and the example in the [issue to add Optional Maintenance Note](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/348299) does not really help me to understand.

- So, what is the purpose of the optional maintenance note ?
- When do we need to look at this message ?
- In the issue, they said it is not for casual user, so is it dedicated only for developers ?
- Also, can you give me an example of what an optional message can be ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/348299) you linked, I think, answers the question.

The Maintenance Note field would contain information relevant to other developers managing this GitLab Runner. e.g. - What machine does it run on, how many cores, how much ram, what OS? Basically, any information about this specific GitLab Runner instance you think would be relevant to share with other devs on this project.

It's perfectly fine to leave this field blank.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks a lot for the answer !